# Conver toDateString to read 'MMM DD'

Tags: string, date, object

Super noob to JavaScript. Would like to create a `DateObject`, but am still stuck.

Wondering how I can convert a date from `toDateString` to custom '`MMM DD`'.

> Tue Mar 09 2014 > Mar 09

*basically, need to parse out the day of the week and the year.

I would like to add any additional objects and functions to this(already converting from UTC):

```
 function dateChange(date) {
return date.toDateString();
}
```

Thanks in advance; looking forward to learning where I am going wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), although it only makes sense if you're consistently using that same date format.

Or, you could use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var splitString = date.toDateString().split(" ");
return splitString[1]+" "+splitString[2];
```

If you want a more flexible library, check out [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) (specificially, the [FormatSpecifiers](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers) would be useful).